# Ubuntu 15.04 no wired internet connection after update

Tags: updates, internet

Since updating ubuntu 10 minutes ago our Ubuntu server no longer has a wired internet connection.  The LAN is still working fine because I'm connected to the server but:

```
ping www.google.com
```

returns unknown host.

My ifconfig information is:

[image]

The result of ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 is:

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is officially past End of Life, and no longer supported here.  You will need to upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu to get continued support.

Comment: Oh, I only installed it a year ago.  Ok I'll upgrade.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Though the problem is I can't update my version of Ubuntu without an internet connection

Comment: try pinging without dns : ping -c 1 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your dns server problem. Try adding dns servers manually.

`nmcli connection edit` *double tab here and choose your connection*

( If you don't know which one is your active connection you can ran : `nmcli connection show --active` )

```
set ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
save
quit
```

`nmcli connection down` *you connection*
`nmcli connection up` *your connection*

if this wont help disable auto dns :

```
set ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes  
save  
quit
```

down and up your connection

Temporary you can paste to **/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8  
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Look for Name Resolution section :
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't have nmcli installed and I don't have an internet connection to install it, is there another way?

Comment: Edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the end of the file.  Remember to use sudo when editing.  Then run `sudo service resolvconf restart`.  Remember also to undo these changes at a later time...